# Can't get textbox search to work with dropdown condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have 2 MS SQL tables noun and verb. On an ASP.net page I have a dropdown with unbound items verb(selected value 1) and noun(selected value 2). I have a textbox and a search button and an unbound gridview1.

I want to be able to enter text in textbox1 and depending on the selection of the dropdown,
I want it to either search the verb table or the noun table and return those results in Gridview1. thank you

here is what i have so far, it doesnt throw errors, it just doesn't work beyond the first if statement. My connection string code is omitted, but it is called vid.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "1")
    {
        string str = "select * from verb where(english like '%' + @search + '%')";

        SqlCommand xp = new SqlCommand(str, vid);
        xp.Parameters.Add("@search", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text;

        vid.Open();
        xp.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = xp;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "verb");
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        vid.Close();

        if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "2")
        {
            string stx = "select * from noun where(english like '%' + @search + '%')";
            SqlCommand xr = new SqlCommand(stx, vid);

            vid.Open();
            xr.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataAdapter dr = new SqlDataAdapter();
            dr.SelectCommand = xr;
            DataSet dss = new DataSet();
            dr.Fill(dss, "noun");
            GridView1.DataSource = dss;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            vid.Close();
        } } }
```

Comment: If you put a break point on line `if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "1")`, then what is the value of `SelectedValue`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using nested if like

```
if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "1")
{
    //Populated from verb table
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "2")
    {
        //Populated from noun table
    }
}
```

Change it to as `DropDownList1.SelectedValue` can either be `1` or `2`

```
if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "1")
{
    //Populated from verb table
}else if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == "2")
{
    //Populated from noun table
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you Satpal! thats all it needed.